# Unity particle system only plays if i hit SIMULATE button

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a prefab with a particle system attached. In the code I play the particle by using this code

```
                ps.enableEmission = true;
```

When i run the game, and that code executes, the particle emitter does not emit anything in the "game" window unless i press simulate button in the "scene" window.

Anybody knows why?

Comment: Did you know their is a StackExchange site dedicated to game dev? You should check it out http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ as it has lots of Unity based questions and answers.

As for your actual issue I'd hazard a guess that the particle system has an emit function that you need to call in a loop to get it to emit continuously and that you aren't doing that. Just a guess though, could be way off!

Answer (score 1):

For the emission property to work the particle system has to actually be playing. To do this you can either enable `Play On Awake` in the `ParticleSystem` component or you use the `Play` method on an instance of the `ParticleSystem` component.

As a side note, if you are using 5.3+ the `enableEmission` property is now obsolete and you may want to consider using the `emission` property. One thing to keep in mind when using this property is you have to assign it to a variable before attempting to modify it:

```
public ParticleSystem _ps;
...    
private void Update()
{
    ParticleSystem.EmissionModule module = _ps.emission;
    module.enabled = true;
}
```

**UPDATE #1**

In response to your tractor beam example in the comments I would probably suggest using `SetActive` on the game object that has the `ParticleSystem` component. By using `SetActive` it will prevent extra particles being emitted and will destroy any that are active, i.e. those currently in the scene.

If you use the `Emission` property, then it will prevent the emission of extra particles, but it will not destroy any that have already been emitted.

One other approach would be to use `Play` and `Stop` methods but these, as with the `emission` property, will not destroy any active particles. If you use these methods, then some things to watch out for are:

- If the `Prewarm` option is not enabled, then `Play` does not start
  emitting particles (not sure why this happens)
- The `isPlaying` property will remain `true` as along as there are
  active particles in the scene. Once these die, then it will
  be set to `false`
- The `Stop` method will not destroy particles active in the scene
- If the `ParticleSystem` has stopped and you call `Play` while there are particles active
  in the scene, then all active particles are destroyed and the
  `ParticleSystem` starts emitting a new set of particles

Comment: motoSV, thanks I will try that, its been driving me crazy, no matter what i do it didnt work, only when i manually press the simulate button in the "Scene" button, i will try that thanks.

Comment: I'm actually using it for a tractor beam, so i have to turn it on and off all the time, i will try what you have and let you know, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check out to see if particle GameObject is active when you call ps.enableEmission = true; on it. To show or hide particles i normally use gameObject.setActive() not ps.enableEmission.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

My particle was not simulating and after I changed the culling Mode to Automatic everything worked. The default is pause and catch-up.